# Crash when I convert PDF pages to PNG images

Tags: iphone, image, ios, pdf, uiscrollview

I need to convert each page of a PDF document to PNG images. These images are then displayed in a scrollView. I need to create two images per page: one at the screen dimension, and one 2.5 times bigger (it is used when the user zoom in the scrollView).

My problem is that I have sometimes memory warnings and crashes when I create big images.
The way  I do it is well-known:

```
    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    float pdfScale = 2.5*self.view.frame.size.height/pageRect.size.height;
    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);    

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size); 
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);    
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, pdfScale,-pdfScale); 
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The problem occurs on iPhone 3G/3GS and iPod Touch.
How can I limit the memory consumption while still having a zoom scale of 2.5 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to create static images for the pages at all?  Why not re-render the PDF page as needed at the higher zoom scale?

Comment: An observation for the code above, it does not handle the page CropBox and rotation properly. Please see here for more details: http://ipdfdev.com/2011/03/23/display-a-pdf-page-on-the-iphone-and-ipad/. Regarding the memory problem, a letter size page converted to image at 250% zoom, considering 96dpi for 100% zoom generates an image of 2040x2640 pixels. At 32bpp (4 bytes per pixel) the image takes about 20MB.

Comment: @BradLarson It's to long to render "in real-time" the PDF page at higher scale.
@SorinNistor Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a webview to display the PDF, that takes care of the zooming and memory issues. Basically rendering the vector format PDF to a bitmap PNG at a large size is possibly not the most appropriate design decision. Without knowing what your requirements for the PNG are though, it's hard to comment.

Comment: thanks for your answer Roger. I already use webview for iPhone 3G. But for iPhone 3GS and other new devices, i prefer using mu own PDF reader. 
I don't have any special requirement on PNG images. They are only used to be displayed on iPhone screen. Do you thing that conversion to JPEG is more relevant ?